# JavaScript/JQuery - Image object getters return wrong values

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Here is what I am trying to do : user will upload a picture with an input `type="file"` on my server. Some AJAX code will send it into my database and move it to the right folder after some verifications.

Then, JS will instantly display it so the user can resize it if he wants to. For that, I am creating an overlay that will match the size and the position of the displayed picture.

Problem is, it seems that my code is too fast to actually retrieve the picture properties in time.

As for width, height will be 0 px, and top and the left will be wrong values. If I upload another picture, it will replace the previous one, but still, those properties will match the erased picture, not the new one.

When I do this step by step with browser debugger, it works and I get the correct values, but not if I just proceed as if I was a simple user.

I tried some `$(picture).done()` or `picture.onload, picture.complete` before setting the picture properties to my div, but the issue remains.

Here is the code :

```
$('#submitPicture').on('input', function ()
{
$.ajax({
//...
}).done(function (data)
{
  var div = $('#setPicture').get(0);
  var dragDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var picture = document.createElement('img');

  dragDiv.id = 'draggable';

  picture.id = 'picture';
  picture.src = data.filePath;

  if ($(div).find('#picture'))
  {
    $(div).find('#picture').remove();
  }

  $(div).append(dragDiv);
  $(div).append(picture);

  $(picture).done(function ()
  {
      $(dragDiv).css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: picture.y,
                        left: picture.x,
                        width: picture.naturalWidth,
                        height: picture.naturalHeight
                       });
  });

});
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in assuming that it must be a timing issue. You say that you tried using `onload` but I wonder if maybe there was some other issue at play, because that definitely should work. See example:

```js
var url = 'https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-background-with-low-poly-design_1048-8478.jpg';
var img = document.createElement('img');
console.log('immediate = ',img.naturalWidth);
img.addEventListener('load', function(evt){
  console.log('load1 = ', img.naturalWidth);
});

img.onload = function(evt){
  console.log('load2 = ', img.naturalWidth);
};

img.src = url;
```

I don't think `.done` will work because that specifically works with a deferred object, of which the `HTMLImageElement`is not.

I don't know if it actually matters... but I prefer to bind to the load event before assigning the `src`. Out of the fear that in the case where the image was cached it might fire immediately. Not sure if that's possible.

The only other thing I can think of is there is a race condition with whatever you are doing on the server-side. Maybe the client-side is making a request for the image before the server has finished storing it and is actually getting a 404 when they try to load the image?